# How can I merge rows from the same dataframe with a mix of null values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, merge, pivot

This problem started when I used pivot_table on my initial table that contained:

```
col_1         col_2      col_3  col_4   col_5   year    index     value
Company X   category 1  A Ltd.  1234    CAD    2019       1     -0.788363
Company X   category 1  A Ltd.  1234    CAD    2018       2     -1.381539
Company X   category 1  A Ltd.  1234    CAD    2017       3     -1.073418
Company Y   category 1  B Ltd.  4321    USD    2019       4     -1.475593
Company Y   category 1  B Ltd.  4321    USD    2018       5     -2.839125
Company Y   category 1  B Ltd.  4321    USD    2017       6     -2.243862
```

I used this code to pivot the value into three years:

```
df= pd.pivot_table(df, index=['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3', 'col_4',
   'col_5', 'index'], columns='year', values='value')\
    .reset_index()
df.columns.name=None
```

So it resulted in this:

```
col_1        col_2     col_3    col_4   col_5   index   2017     2018      2019
Company X   category 1  A Ltd.  1234    CAD       1              -0.788363  
Company X   category 1  A Ltd.  1234    CAD       2   -1.381539     
Company X   category 1  A Ltd.  1234    CAD       3                       -1.073418
Company Y   category 1  B Ltd.  4321    USD       4                       -1.475593
Company Y   category 1  B Ltd.  4321    USD       5   -2.839125     
Company Y   category 1  B Ltd.  4321    USD       6               -2.243862
```

How can I merge those value in the years so that they are in the same row? Or should I have pivoted differently?
Thanks.

Comment: I would try getting rid of index, it won't let you put them on the same row since that one is unique. If that alone doesn't work, you can do a group_by on the result.